# Xamarin Android notifcation - turn on screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a notification thats turns on the screen when it happens(same as calls/ sms)

I have this

```
            public void NotifyWithIntent(string title, string text, DateTime time, Type intentTarget) {
            int id = 0;
            var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, intentTarget);
            Android.App.Notification.Builder builder = new Android.App.Notification.Builder(Application.Context).SetContentTitle(title).SetContentText(text).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon2).SetAutoCancel(true).SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification));

            NotificationManager notificationManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, intent.Class);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetWhen(RepositoryService.TimeMillis(time));
            builder.SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max);
         builder.SetCategory(NotificationPriorityCategory.Calls.ToString());
            Android.App.Notification notification = builder.Build();
            notification.Defaults |= NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
            notificationManager?.Notify("", id, notification);
```

What can i add to get the screen to turn on when the notification occurs ?

/Birger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` to your wake lock flags:

```
var powerManager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(PowerService);
var wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.ScreenDim | WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup, "StackOverflow");
wakeLock.Acquire();
await Task.Delay(1000);
wakeLock.Release();
```

> Wake lock flag: Turn the screen on when the wake lock is acquired.

Re: [PowerManager: ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP)

Comment: Works great:) Thank you.